# Run TeamSpeak3 as a service on Debian 8

Tags: linux, service, debian, vps

I've spend few hours trying to find solution and already visited.

I'm stuck in point of starting service (all other done well, and I successfully can start teamspeak server manually)

I figured out that my problem is related to my version of Debian.

my uname -rv return:

```
 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.43-2 (2017-04-30)
```

my last service file is as follows:

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          ts3
# Required-Start:    $network
# Required-Stop:     $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: TeamSpeak3 Server Daemon
# Description:       Starts/Stops/Restarts the TeamSpeak Server 

Daemon
### END INIT INFO 
set -e

# PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DESC="TeamSpeak3 Server"
NAME=teamspeak3-server
USER=ts3user
DIR=/home/ts3user/teamspeak3-server


DAEMON=$DIR/ts3server_startscript.sh
PIDFILE=/home/ts3user/teamspeak3-server/ts3server.pid
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/ts3

# Gracefully exit if the package has been removed.
# test -x $DAEMON || exit 0
# sleep 2
su $USER -c $DAEMON $1
```

i used

```
sudo service ts3 start

sudo systemctl start ts3.service
```

both return an error:

```
Job for ts3.service failed. See 'systemctl status ts3.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

sudo service ts3 status return:

```
 ● ts3.service - LSB: TeamSpeak3 Server Daemon
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/ts3)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-06-07 21:08:45 CEST; 49s ago
Process: 8941 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/ts3 start (code=exited, status=2)

Jun 07 21:08:45 vps419654.ovh.net su[8942]: Successful su for ts3user by root
Jun 07 21:08:45 vps419654.ovh.net su[8942]: + ??? root:ts3user
Jun 07 21:08:45 vps419654.ovh.net su[8942]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user ts3us...=0)
Jun 07 21:08:45 vps419654.ovh.net ts3[8941]: Usage: /home/ts3user/teamspeak3-server/ts3server_s...us}
Jun 07 21:08:45 vps419654.ovh.net systemd[1]: ts3.service: control process exited, code=exited ...s=2
Jun 07 21:08:45 vps419654.ovh.net systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: TeamSpeak3 Server Daemon.
Jun 07 21:08:45 vps419654.ovh.net systemd[1]: Unit ts3.service entered failed state.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

I followed many guides but all with no success

```
my user for this puropse is **ts3user**
TS3 server is located in **/home/ts3user/teamspeak3-server/**
file that start TS3 server is **ts3server_startscript.sh**
file ts3 (service) is located in **/etc/init.d**
```

What I've done wrong in this ts3 file ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

First make script executable (not realy needed in case of ts3)

```
sudo chmod +x /home/ts3user/teamspeak3-server/ts3server_startscript.sh
```

next try to change owner for files

```
cd /home/ts3user/
chown ts3user:ts3user teamspeak3-server/ -R
```

and then try to run server as a ts3user

```
su - ts3user
cd /home/ts3user/teamspeak3-server/
./ts3server_startscript.sh
```

if everything went right, try to run service as this user

```
service ts3 start
```

Comment: it seems that ts3user can run ./ts3server_startscript.sh
But this not solved problem, error in service ts3 persist